# The Merge: should I stick with jsonrpc or move to eth api's?

Tags: blocks, clients, eth-2.0, prysm, the-merge

I'm trying to understand what happens after the merge, what should my frontend clients do. Should they stick with the `execution layer` (EL) `jsonrpc` (they'll still have access to the latest transactions, right?) or should I move my frontend clients to use the `Consensus Layer` (CL) `Rest API`?

Testing on `kiln` shows me that the EL will show synced, even when the consensus layer is still syncing. So given that the 'latest' state of the eth client I'm connected to is on the CL `slots`, then maybe I should drop `jsonrpc` altogether?

Also, if I move to the `Rest API` and I have a `$blockNumber`, I can't use the api to search for the `slot` that it's related to (slot with `execution_payloads.blockNumber == $blockNumber`). So maybe I should definitely stick with `jsonrpc`?

- Execution Layer: geth or erigon
- Consensus Layer: prysm

Currently my front end is getting latest blocks, events and processing receipts/logs from latest blocks, so everything is `jsonrpc` and research tells me that I need to only use tag `finalized` (or `safe`) instead of `latest`. Research also gives me impression `slots` on the CL are the canonical 'head'... so swimming back and forward here

Answer (score 1):

The merge will involve switching the consensus algorithm from PoW to PoS. If your app uses json-rpc endpoints like geth, infura, etc. then making sure the node supports the merge should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The Merge is designed to not require changes for most applications, so sticking to the JSON-RPC is expected to work. Still, you are **strongly recommended** to use a testnet like Ropsten (and Goerli when it is ready) to verify your applications, like frontend clients.

From https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/06/03/ropsten-merge-ttd/

#### As an application or tooling developer, what should I do?

> Now is the time to ensure that your front-end code, tooling,
> deployment pipeline and other off-chain components work as intended.
> We strongly recommend that developers run through a complete testing &
> deployment cycle on Ropsten (or Kiln) and report any issues with tools
> or dependencies to those projects’ maintainers. If you are unsure where to open an issue, please use [this repository](https://github.com/eth-clients/merge-testnets/).

Additionally, you should note that all testnets aside from Sepolia and Goerli will be deprecated post-merge. If you are a user of Ropsten, Rinkeby or Kiln, you should plan to migrate to Goerli or Sepolia. More information about this can be found [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2022/06/21/testnet-deprecation/).